# Jenkins pytest not found

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest, cicd

After installing pytest using requirements.txt in the build stage. I still get pytest not found error in my testing stage. I am new to jenkins I don't really understand how the environment in jenkins works.

Here is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent{
                docker { image 'python:3' }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'

                withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
                    sh '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
                    sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            agent{
                docker { image 'python:3' }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
                
                withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
                    sh 'pytest ./tests/unit/test_models.py'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're running `Build` and `Test` on different containers because both of them have a separate `agent` definition (even though the same agent is used).

You could try extracting the `agent` definition to global pipeline context, i.e.:

```
pipeline {
    agent{
        docker { image 'python:3' }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'

                withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
                    sh '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
                    sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
                
                withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
                    sh 'pytest ./tests/unit/test_models.py'
                }
            }
        }
(...)
```

Comment: I tried this but still has the same error pytest not found

Comment: Then maybe unifying `Build` and `Test` into one stage so that you can execute `pytest` right after your call to `pip install ...`?

Comment: Can't work too, not sure why pytest is not recognized even after installing.

Comment: I tried pip list too and it clearly shows pytest is installed.

Comment: Is it `pytest` which is not found or is it `./tests/unit/test_models.py`?

Comment: pytest is not found